# Access an HTML control on ASP Master Page from the code behind of a Content Page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, code-behind

I have an ASP.NET / C# application in which the Master Page contain the main menu of my application and several content pages that depend of this master page.

I would like to highlight the menu link of my master page corresponding to the current content page displayed.

To do that, I already have a CSS class dedicated to this (called "selected")

Thus, I was trying to access the Master Page link I want to highlight from the content page by using its ID and do something like that (in the content page) :

```
HtmlLink currentMenu = (HtmlLink) Master.FindControl("idOfTheLinkToHighlight");
currentMenu.Attributes.Add("class", "selected");
```

But I get the following exception :

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink
```

Can anybody help me on this ?
Thanks

Comment: Can we see how you declare your link in the master page?

Comment: It looks like your control declaration is not of type HtmlLink to which you're trying to cast, control declaration code would help as Gregoire already noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way, try

```
(HtmlGenericControl)currentMenu = (HtmlGenericControl) Master.FindControl("idOfTheLinkToHighlight");
currentMenu.Attributes.Add("class", "selected");
```

it should work because HtmlGenericControl has also attributes

Comment: Yes exactly ! Just the time for e to refresh this page and it is what I tried. It works fine (and my problem was just a mistake that came to my mind thanks to your first answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Was messing around with this for a while as I needed it to be a HTML link.  Turns out that you need runat="server" in the   e.g.

```
<head runat="server" id=aHead>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just for a reference, I needed to do something similar and in order to get it working I added the runat="server" to the body tag (thanks to this thread).

Comment: This is exactly what Buswell's answer from two years prior says.