# Override in child page content and style of nav from master

Tags: c#, css

Do you know a method that completely wipes out a `<nav class="navClass">` from a master page, or replaces it by `<nav> (no content, no styling in between) </nav>`? 
I tried

```
<style>
    .navClass { width: 0px !important; }
</style>
```

This takes effect on styling only, but if I have text in between, it will not be removed.

I have solved this in c# by putting a condition on the masterpage.

`<% if ( // condition to not apply for child of certain type { %> 
//here, original definition with content and style 
<% } %>`

But I want to know if there is something more effective that can be used on the child directly to remove the `nav`, in either c# or css, avoiding javascript. 
Maybe I can assign it with ID in master and use it to override it in the child?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this link for finding a solution. Check if it is useful [Access an HTML control on ASP Master Page from the code behind of a Content Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301904/access-an-html-control-on-asp-master-page-from-the-code-behind-of-a-content-page)

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do is to remove the classes for the **`nav`** element via jQuery.

Code below will remove all associated classes for **`nav`**.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('nav').removeClass();
});
```