# How to access site master page controls from code behind in ASP?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have my navigation bar in my site master page set up, and I'm trying to access it from the code behind each page that references it, in order to change the 'active' selected item on the pageload event. I've set each li tag to a unique id and to runat="server" but I still can't reference it. Here's what I've got so far on the master page.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar2" >
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active" id="nbHome" runat="server"><a href="HomePage.aspx">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="Gallery.aspx" id="nbGallery" runat="server">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="Services.aspx" id="nbServices" runat="server">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="Tutorials.aspx" id="nbTutorials" runat="server">Tutorials</a></li>
                <li><a href="FAQ.aspx" id="nbFAQ" runat="server">F.A.Q.</a></li>
                <li><a href="Contact.aspx" id="nbContact" runat="server">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access an HTML control on ASP Master Page from the code behind of a Content Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301904/access-an-html-control-on-asp-master-page-from-the-code-behind-of-a-content-page)

Comment: The difference being that I do not have a dedicated CSS class set up for it, and I'm not getting any exceptions - I simply can't figure out how to reference the control from the PageLoad event.

Answer (score 1):

You use `FindControl` to look for a `HtmlControl` in the Master.

```
HtmlControl control = Master.FindControl("nbGallery") as HtmlControl;
control.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
```

This requires `using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;` at the top of the .cs file.

Comment: No change, sadly - the selected item remains inactive. Going to fiddle with it a bit though. Using similar code for the old selected item to do     
    control.Attributes.Remove("class"); 
works fine though

Comment: It works on my test enviroment when this snippet is used in a Page to search for the Control in the Master. If you use it in the code behind of the master, then you need to remove `Master.`

Comment: It successfully finds it, and can remove the class from the pre-selected one. I'm attempting to reference it (successfully) from the PageLoad of one of the aspx pages that references the master page, it just doesn't change the class itself.

Comment: What do you mean by "change class", did you inspect the html